# Getting the oldest and newest elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

Does elasticsearch have an API to return the creation timestamp of an index (or sort by it)? I want to delete the oldest 'n' indexes of some "index-type" and restrict some queries to only the newest index. The naming convention that I use for indexes is something like: `<indextype>_<client_hostname>_<batch_name>.`

Comment: Where and how do you define the name of the indexes? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `_timestamp` field is per document. If you retrieve the oldest document based on the `_timestamp` it might help, but the index could have been previously created using the create index api. In fact, an index is by default automatically created when you index the first document into it (unless you disable this behaviour), but you can also create an index upfront.

I think I would add the timestamp to the name of the index too and manage this outside of elasticsearch. Remember that you can also close an index without deleting the data if you need to.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the responses. Adding timestamp is not always possible, especially if the clients are distributed. I'll just leave this as a shortcoming in elasticsearch. Hope Kimchi reads this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has a [`_timestamp` field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html).  It is disabled by default, though, so you will need to enable it, using a mapping such as that provided in the documentation, with: `"_timestamp" : { "enabled" : true }`

Comment: So, considering that this field was not already enabled, there seems to be no way to get index creation time. _stat API provides various statistics for the index (wrt time and size) but no indication of when the index was created (or the create timestamp of index files on disk).